# how to get the axis values on the HoverTool - Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, charts, bokeh

I have written a code that reads from a .csv files and converts it into a pandas dataframe. I then proceed to plot the chart with candlesticks. The chart itself is good but when i try to use the HoverTools i cannot seem to add the axis values to the tool. 
I used column data source but i wasnt able to understand it.

```
  import pandas as pd

  from math import pi

  from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

  from bokeh.models import HoverTool

  df = pd.read_csv('/Users/robindhillon/Desktop/pyfiles/EURUSD.csv')

  df.columns = ['date','open','high','low','close','volume']

  df['date'] = pd.to_datetime([x[:-9] for x in 
  df['date'].squeeze().tolist()], dayfirst=True)

  inc = df.close > df.open
  dec = df.open > df.close
  w = 86400000


  hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[
        ('date',   '@date'),
        ('open',  '@open' ), 
        ('high', '@high'  ),
        ('low',   '@low'   ),
        ('close',  '@close'),
    ],

    formatters={
        'date' : 'datetime', 
        'open' : 'numeral',   
        'high' : 'numeral',
        'low'  : 'numeral',
        'close': 'numeral',                  
    },

    mode='vline'
)

   TOOLS = 'pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,crosshair'

   p = figure(x_axis_type = 'datetime', tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1200, 
   title='test')

   p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
   p.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0.3

   p.add_tools(hover)

   p.segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color="black")

   p.vbar(df.date[inc], w, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], 
   fill_color="#12C98C", line_color="black")

   p.vbar(df.date[dec], w, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], 
   fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

   output_file("candlestick.html", title="candlestick.py example")

   show(p)  # open a browser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field names that begin with @ are associated with columns in a `ColumnDataSource`. For instance the field name "@date" will display values from the "date" column whenever a hover is triggered. If the hover is for the 17th glyph, then the hover tooltip will correspondingly display the 17th date value. The hover tool won't work if you use field names that begin with @ without a `ColumnDataSource`

```
import pandas as pd
from math import pi
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/robindhillon/Desktop/pyfiles/EURUSD.csv')
df.columns = ['date','open','high','low','close','volume']
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime([x[:-9] for x in 
df['date'].squeeze().tolist()], dayfirst=True)

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 86400000

hover = HoverTool(
  tooltips=[
    ('date',   '@date{%F}'),
    ('open',  '@open' ), 
    ('high', '@high'  ),
    ('low',   '@low'   ),
    ('close',  '@close'),
  ],
  formatters={
    'date' : 'datetime', 
    'open' : 'numeral',   
    'high' : 'numeral',
    'low'  : 'numeral',
    'close': 'numeral',                  
  },
  mode='vline'
)

df['dateinc'] = df.date[inc]
df['openinc'] = df.open[inc]
df['closeinc'] = df.close[inc]
df['datedec'] = df.date[dec]
df['opendec'] = df.open[dec]
df['closedec'] = df.close[dec]

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

TOOLS = 'pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,crosshair'

p = figure(x_axis_type = 'datetime', tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1200, 
title='test')

p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha = 0.3

p.add_tools(hover)
p.segment('date', 'high', 'date', 'low', color="black", source=source)
p.vbar('dateinc', w, 'openinc', 'closeinc', fill_color="#12C98C", line_color="black", source=source)

p.vbar('datedec', w, 'opendec', 'closedec', fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black", source=source)

output_file("candlestick.html", title="candlestick.py example")

show(p)  # open a browser
```

Comment: Your method worked, except that the date field still shows values like 1502308902

Comment: Edited my answer, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `@field_name` hover tool specification, there are also some "special variables" to display specific information not-related to the data source. To display the data-space value of the x-coordinate under the cursor, use `$x`

Comment: I tried doing that, given that is the best solution. However on my chart the x-axis shows the datetime data but when i add into the hover tool it shows data like (1.502e+12)

Comment: That will happen by default regardless, since the underlying units for datetime is milliseconds since epoch. You would need to use a custom hover formatter as described in the docs to customize the formatting.

Comment: So i followed your advice and i went ahead and added a custom hover tool with the formatter  = 'date' : 'datetime' and specified the format. i even tried to format the x axis with the DatetimeTickFormatter and still no luck. I double checked my datetime column and it is fine.

Comment: You'd have to post real complete code to speculate more.